# dotnetinstall UI - dropping the mainPage dialog

Tags: user-interface, windows-installer, dotnetinstaller

I have created a XML using dotnet installer editor, this creates an .exe for my MSI. but what i want to achieve is to not display the mainpage of the installer when the exe is run, and only show my MSI UI, i can get rid of the "progress dialog" but not this annoying dialog. Please Assist.

Comment: You should clarify some things - what is the dotnet installer editor? WiX? Visual Studio Setup Project? And you may need to say exactly what the main page of the installer is - many tools that build MSI files have choices of dialogs and they are not all the same.

Comment: i don't think its a question for you to answer. Those that understand wix will know what i am talking about

Comment: Well, that could be funny if it wasn't impolite... definitely not a question for the expert like you, @PhilDW :)